# How can I configure the a Gradle configuration, specifically "permitUnusedDeclared" in the gradle-dependency-analyze plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using the [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) plugin to analyze my Gradle project's dependencies.  [The plugin documentation](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze#configurations) states that it allows specifying a "permitUnusedDeclared" configuration to define dependencies which should be handled in a special way.  However, I cannot figure out how to configure this within Gradle.  It appears that I am not the first person to have this issue, as there is [an open bug report](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze/issues/27) requesting improved documentation around this specific area.

How, therefore, would I configure my build.gradle to specify this configuration?  As a concrete example, let's say I wanted to use "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.4.4.RELEASE" and "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.4.4.RELEASE" as the configured value.

I can see in [the Plugin definition](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze/blob/37e3fa35a64d2164ff9733829cb46d41380d018e/src/main/groovy/ca/cutterslade/gradle/analyze/AnalyzeDependenciesPlugin.groovy) that this is being added; I just have no clue how to actually configure it within my project.

Answer (score 0):

Per a new [comment](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze/issues/27#issuecomment-279497718) on the bug report, the solution is to add these to the dependencies section of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.4.4.RELEASE'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.4.4.RELEASE'
  permitUnusedDeclared 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.4.4.RELEASE'
  permitUnusedDeclared 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.4.4.RELEASE'
}
```